# Unable to subscribe to storage event in standard logic app workflow

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to subscribe to storage account (Blob Created ) event using the event grid connector (Workflow URL) in the standard logic app and it fails with the below error.  However, if i use the same connector in consumption logic app it works fine.

[image: Error]

[image: Event Grid Connector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have create a workflow using `When a resource event occurs` trigger and got the same error alike you.*

> However, if i use the same connector in consumption logic app it works fine.

Yes, In consumption logic app it will work because the validation happens internally but as given in this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/using-single-tenant-logic-app-workflow-endpoint-as-event-grid/ba-p/3055814), you need to explicitly validate the subscription handshake in order to receive the events in standard logic app.

[image]

Then I modified my workflow as below and it started working for me.

[image]

It will check for event type `Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent` which will be received at the time of event creation.

[image]

Below step is added for handshake validation.

[image]

***Code:***

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "HTTP": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@triggerBody()?['data']?['validationCode']",
                            "method": "POST",
                            "uri": "@{triggerBody()?['data']?['validationUrl']}"
                        },
                        "runtimeConfiguration": {
                            "contentTransfer": {
                                "transferMode": "Chunked"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "Http"
                    }
                },
                "else": {
                    "actions": { }
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                        "equals": [
                                "@triggerBody()?['eventType']",
                                "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": { },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>@{triggerBody()?['data']}</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "Blob Created",
                        "To": "***********.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "office365"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Condition": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": { },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_resource_event_occurs": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "destination": {
                                "endpointType": "webhook",
                                "properties": {
                                    "endpointUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                                }
                            },
                            "filter": {
                                "includedEventTypes": [
                                    "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
                                ]
                            },
                            "topic": "afreenstorage"
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "azureeventgrid"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('*********')}/providers/@{encodeURIComponent('Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccounts')}/resource/eventSubscriptions",
                    "queries": {
                        "x-ms-api-version": "2017-09-15-preview"
                    }
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Then I created the event by using the below URL-

[image]

***Event Creation:***

[image]

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

*Please ensure to add all the actions in your workflow specifically the handshake validation condition action then create the event.*

Comment: It worked...Thanks a lot !!!